# Script fazendo muitas requisições indevidas

Tags: php, javascript

Estou no seguinte dilema, que pode ser simples para muitos aqui, porém, como sou iniciante, estou passando por uma grande dificuldade em um sistema que estou dando suporte...

Ao clicar em um botão, é executado um *script* que retorna dados em JSON. Porém, a cada clique, é como se ele dobrasse a execução deste *script* (Executa 2x, depois executa 4, 8, 16, etc).

Vocês que possuem mais experiência na área, podem me dar uma luz, por favor?

Estou enviando as 2 funções do *script*, para caso as 2 estejam em algum conflito, e o arquivo PHP requisitado.

[image: Várias Requisições]

selectDB

```
    function selectDB(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var pos = document.getElementById('dgn_id').value;
    var postURL= "busca_dgn_pri.php";
    $.ajax({
            async: false,
            type: "POST",
            cache: 'false',
            url: postURL,
            data: {dgn_id: pos},
            success: function(html){
                var dgnData = $.parseJSON(html);

                $('#dgn_pri')
                .append($("<option></option>")
                .attr("value",dgnData.dgn[0].dgn_pri)
                .attr("selected","selected")
                .attr("disabled","disabled")
                .text(dgnData.dgn[0].dgn_pri));
            }
    });
    });
}
```

addOptionSelect

```
 function addOptionSelect(){
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("option").remove();

        $('#btnprox').click(function(){
            $("option").remove();
            addOptionSelect();
            selectDB();
        });
        $('#btnante').click(function(){
            $("option").remove();
            addOptionSelect();
            selectDB();
        });
        $('#btnprim').click(function(){
            $("option").remove();
            addOptionSelect();
            selectDB();
        });
        $('#btnulti').click(function(){
            $("option").remove();
            addOptionSelect();
            selectDB();
        });
        $('#btnnovo').click(function(){
            $("option").remove();
            addOptionSelect();
        });
        $('#btnexcl').click(function(){
            $("option").remove();
            addOptionSelect();
            selectDB();
        });
        $('#btncanc').click(function(){
            $("option").remove();
            addOptionSelect();
            selectDB();
        });
        $('#btnsalv').click(function(){
            $("option").remove();
            addOptionSelect();
            selectDB();
        });

        var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, campo) {
            var nomeCampo = $(campo).attr('name');
            return nomeCampo;
        }).get();

        $.each(sel, function(key, value){
            if (($('option[value='+key+']').length == 0) && (value != "sem_diag")) {
                var campoTxt = $('label[for='+value+']').html();
                $('#dgn_pri')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",campoTxt)
                    .text(campoTxt));                
            } else {
                $("option").remove();
            }
        });

    });
}
```

Arquivo PHP

```
    $pos = $_REQUEST['dgn_id'];

$sql = "SELECT dgn_id, dgn_pri FROM nut_diagnutric WHERE dgn_id = $pos";

$result = $DB->query($sql);

$rows = array();
while($row = $DB->fetchArray($result)){
        $rows[] = $row;
}

$qryResult = array();
$qryResult['dgn'] = array_unique($rows);
echo json_encode($qryResult);
```

Comment: Coloque o parâmetro `event` (a função deve ficar `function(event)`) em cada função dos eventos coloque também o seguinte código `event.preventDefault();` e `event.stopPropagation();` no início de cada evento de click que é chamada a função `selectDB()`. Veja se resolve.

Comment: Coloca pf mais informação do que tem o JSON e o que queres fazer com os dados que vêm do PHP para podermos ajudar mais.

Comment: Essa função function selectDB(){ ..} não precisa de uma subfunção : $(document).ready(function(){}); pois isso só é usado para carregar quando ler o documento, vc pode passar todo o conteúdo desse document ready dentro do seu método direto... senão ele vai ficar lendo várias vezes esse post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Dentro da função tem chamada para ela mesma creio que isso é a raiz do problema, porque toda vez que você faz um click, é feito outro evento, e na proxima vez que o mouse for pressionado dispara 2 eventos( ou mais conforme for incrementando) em paralelo:

```
function addOptionSelect(){
.
.
.
    addOptionSelect();
}
```

Então toda vez que ela chama ela mesma ela "prepara" mais um evento click() ou seja o evento click se propaga gerando esses eventos todos.

Para corrigir de maneira rápida pode mandar um stopimmediatepropagation() dentro do evento click() assim:

```
$('#btnnovo').click(function(e){
...
e.stopimmediatepropagation();
....
});
```

> http://api.jquery.com/event.stopimmediatepropagation/

Outra coisa que eu iria comentar é sobre o `$(document).ready(function () {` mas já foi comentado, então é só se atentar para esse detalhe também, mas no caso em questão não irá surgir efeitos. (apesar de estar errado usa-lo da forma em que esta)

Answer (score 5):

Se entendi bem seu código pode ser resumido a isso:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#btnprox,#btnante,#btnprim,#btnulti,#btnnovo,#btnexcl,#btncanc,#btnsalv').click(function(){
        $("option").remove();
        addOptionSelect();
        selectDB();
    });

    function addOptionSelect(){   
        var sel = $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').map(function(_, campo) {
            var nomeCampo = $(campo).attr('name');
            return nomeCampo;
        }).get();

        $.each(sel, function(key, value){
            if (($('option[value='+key+']').length == 0) && (value != "sem_diag")) {
                var campoTxt = $('label[for='+value+']').html();
                $('#dgn_pri')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",campoTxt)
                    .text(campoTxt));                
            } else {
                $("option").remove();
            }
        });
    }

    function selectDB(){
        var pos = document.getElementById('dgn_id').value;
        var postURL= "busca_dgn_pri.php";
        $.ajax({
                async: false,
                type: "POST",
                cache: 'false',
                url: postURL,
                data: {dgn_id: pos},
                success: function(html){
                    var dgnData = $.parseJSON(html);

                    $('#dgn_pri')
                    .append($("<option></option>")
                    .attr("value",dgnData.dgn[0].dgn_pri)
                    .attr("selected","selected")
                    .attr("disabled","disabled")
                    .text(dgnData.dgn[0].dgn_pri));
                }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Tens algumas ideias no código que são erradas e/ou podem ser a fonte do problema.

De maneira geral quando adicionas elementos novos ao DOM deves adicionar event handlers ao(s) próprio(s) elemento(s). Se vais usar um seletor genérico tipo `$('.minhaClasse')` e já há na página elementos com essa classe e que já têm um event handler, então vais ter código a correr duas vezes.

Outra coisa que não faz muito sentido no teu código é teres a função `addOptionSelect` a chamar-se a sí própria quando o que ela faz é adicionar event handlers. Isso é garantido de adicionar event handlers duplicados, e ter código a correr duas vezes.

Outra coisa que não faz muito sentido é teres `$(document).ready(function () {` dentro dessa função. Tens um problema de lógica. Esse `$(document).ready(function () {` deve ser corrido uma vez no inicio da página carregar, se fôr necessário, e não mais.

Answer (score 4):

O seu problema está no como você criou a função `addOptionSelect`

Para entender de forma mais simples eu simplifiquei a sua função para o mínimo necessário para o problema ocorrer, excluindo apenas o código que chama o addOptionSelect pela primeira vez

```
function addOptionSelect() {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //$("option").remove();

        $("#btnprox").click(function () {
            addOptionSelect();
            console.log("click do btnprox");
        });

        console.log("resto do código");
    });
}
```

Com apenas isso, a primeira vez que clico no botão `btnprox` ele executa como esperado e aparece uma vez a mensagem, porém no cliques seguintes vai dobrando a quantidade de mensagens.

Isso ocorre porque no clique do botão você chama de novo a função addOptionSelect, e esta função adiciona um handler novo para o clique do botão, então na próxima vez que você clica no botão este código é executado 2 vezes, adicionando mais 2 handler para o clique, que na próxima vez executa 4 vezes, adicionado mais 4 handlers para o clique e assim por diante.

O que você precisa fazer é remover o código que adiciona os handlers de dentro desta função e executar ele apenas uma vez quando a página for carregada, como por exemplo

```
function addOptionSelect() {
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //$("option").remove();

        console.log("resto do código");
    });
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#btnprox").click(function () {
        addOptionSelect();
        console.log("click do btnprox");
    }); 
});
```

> Obs, o `$(document).ready` não é realmente necessário dentro do `addOptionSelect`, eu apenas incluí ele no exemplo para tornar o código mais similar ao original e facilitar o entendimento da diferença